# Output of loss is None

Tags: tensorflow

I have to finetune VGG.There are five convolutional layers and then three fully connected layers. Output from the last fully connected layer is the input of the loss function. Following is my code:

```
class vgg16:
    def __init__(self, imgs1,imgs2, weights=None, sess=None):

        self.imgs1 = imgs1
        self.imgs2 = imgs2

        with tf.variable_scope("siamese") as scope:
            self.o1 = self.convlayers(imgs1)
        self.fc_layers()

        self.loss()

        if weights is not None and sess is not None:
                self.load_weights(weights, sess)
            scope.reuse_variables()
            self.o2 = self.convlayers(imgs2)
        self.fc_layers()
        self.loss()

        if weights is not None and sess is not None:
             self.load_weights(weights, sess)
        #create loss function


    def convlayers(self,imgs):
        ....

        # conv1_2
        with tf.name_scope('conv1_2') as scope:
            ......
        # pool1


    ..
)

        .....

        # pool5
        self.pool5 = tf.nn.max_pool(self.conv5_3,
                               ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               padding='SAME',
                               name='pool4')

    def fc_layers(self):
        # fc1
        with tf.name_scope('fc1') as scope:
            ....
        # fc2
        with tf.name_scope('fc2') as scope:
            ...

        # fc3
        with tf.name_scope('fc3') as scope:
            fc3w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4096, 1000],
                                                     dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
        fc3b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[1000], dtype=tf.float32),
                             trainable=True, name='biases')
        self.fc3l = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(self.fc2, fc3w), fc3b)
    def load_weights(self, weight_file, sess):
        weights = np.load(weight_file)
        keys = sorted(weights.keys())
        for i, k in enumerate(keys):
            print i, k, np.shape(weights[k])
            sess.run(self.parameters[i].assign(weights[k]))
    def loss(self):

    loss=tf.nn.l2_loss(self.fc3l)


    self.train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    sess = tf.Session()
    imgs1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 224, 224, 3])#jis size ka bhi imaeg hai usko 224x224 may kar diya or RGB chaeay hmay
    imgs2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 224, 224, 3])
    vgg = vgg16(imgs1,imgs2, 'vgg16_weights.npz', sess)


    img1 = imread('laska.png', mode='RGB')
    img1 = imresize(img1, (224, 224))
    img2 = imread('laska2.jpg', mode='RGB')
    img2 = imresize(img2,(224, 224))

    prob = sess.run(vgg.train_step, feed_dict={vgg.imgs1: [img1],vgg.imgs2: [img2]})
    print('loss is:')
    print(prob)
```

The problem is that the output of prob is None. Kindly indicate what I am doing wrong.

PS: I am following siamese architecture. Input to both branches are different images here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The op `self.train_step` does not return anything, it just calculates gradients and updates variables. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/train/optimizers#Optimizer.minimize).

What you need to do is to save reference to `loss` tensor in your `vgg16` class like this:

```
self.loss=tf.nn.l2_loss(self.fc3l)
```

and then execute both train_step and loss operations in single `sess.run`:

```
_, loss_value = sess.run([vgg.train_step, vgg.loss], feed_dict=...)
print('loss is:')
print(loss_value)
```